# Criterion of holomorphy

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

I have posted a similar question on MSE few days ago, but it received no attention.

Let $G$ be a homogeneous (or even symmetric) domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $u:G\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.

Q1. Assume that $\frac{u\circ\Phi}{u}$ is holomorphic for any biholomorphism $\Phi:G\to G$. Is it true that then $u$ is holomorphic itself?

Q2. Assume that for any biholomorphism $\Phi:G\to G$ there is a holomorphic function $v_{\Phi}:G\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ such that $\frac{u\circ\Phi}{u}=\left|\frac{v_{\Phi}\circ\Phi}{v_{\Phi}}\right|$. Is it true that there is a holomorphic function $v:G\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ such that $u=|v|$?

Comment: What is the definition of "homogeneous"? homogeneous under the self-biholomorphism group? under the action of some real Lie group by self-biholomorphisms? else?

Comment: @YCor first; i think it's a standard term

Comment: Thank you very much to this complement of information, I'm happy to know that it's a standard term in your community. So I'll try to guess between several potential reasonable definitions.

Comment: @YCor I think a homogeneous space without specification of the group is usually meant to be the space in which the group of automorphisms (in the sense of the appropriate structure/category, which is usually clear from the context) acts transitively. Am I wrong? Even if I am, no need to get so hostile.

Comment: My doubt was inside my first comment: in the context of manifolds, homogeneous often means homogeneous under the action of some (finite-dimensional and connected) Lie group, which in the holomorphic context would be a priori a stronger requirement. (Also I didn't notice the word "first" in your first answer meant that the answer to my request was the first option, so I interpreted as "I think it's a standard term" without answer... sorry)